# HTTP header compression

Tags: http, http-headers, http-compression

HTTP headers aren't very efficient. Dozens of bytes more than necessary are used between the minimal method and response headers.

Has there been any proposal to standardize a binary or compressed format for HTTP?

Is there a similar standard besides HTTP which is better suited to interactive mobile applications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As referenced in [Stackoverflow - How to compress HTTP response headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110546/how-to-compress-http-response-headers):

See Google's SPDY research project: [Google's SPDY research project](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/11/2x-faster-web.html)

From [SPDY whitepaper](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper):

> **The role of header compression**
>
> Header compression resulted in an ~88%
>   reduction in the size of request
>   headers and an ~85% reduction in the
>   size of response headers. On the
>   lower-bandwidth DSL link, in which the
>   upload link is only 375 Kbps, request
>   header compression in particular, led
>   to significant page load time
>   improvements for certain sites (i.e.
>   those that issued large number of
>   resource requests). We found a
>   reduction of 45 - 1142 ms in page load
>   time simply due to header compression.

Comment: SPDY looks pretty good and comprehensive, +1. I need to see if it's lightweight…

Answer (score 6):

[HTTP/2.0](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/), currently in a drafting phase, is an evolution of SPDY designed to address these issues.

Specifically, it replaces the request lines and headers with a compact binary format. It adds a server push facility and multiplexes streams over a single connection, to avoid the overhead of multiple connections and head-of-queue blocking. There are various other goodies.

I am working on a lightweight/cut-to-fit C++ implementation.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question and I think it needs an update. Although I have no deeper understanding of this topic myself I stumbled over [this very good article which explains the HPACK compression of HTTP/2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/).

In short it says:

- SPDY was vulnerable to the CRIME attack so no one really used its header compression
- HTTP/2 supports a new dedicated header compression algorithm, called HPACK
- HPACK is resilient to CRIME
- HPACK uses three methods of compression: Static Dictionary, Dynamic Dictionary, Huffman Encoding

Comment: CRIME was much talked-about in the development of HPACK, but it's not so clear that users were actually concerned about it. It was a very difficult attack to mount and prevention is a matter of total website design, not only the protocol. Yeah, this question needs a new answer on HPACK.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, I would say no and no. HTTP was invented, IMHO, to do away with proprietary server/client communication. Does that mean you can't still do proprietary server/client communication? No. Go ahead and write your own server and protocol, open up whatever port you want and have a ball.

Comment: Binary does not mean proprietary. There are RFCs for IP header compression, and I want the equivalent for the next level up the stack.

Comment: I stand corrected then.  If the RFCs do exist, they are not widely adopted which makes them only a step above proprietary for current practical use.

Comment: Even uncompressed headers are binary at lower levels (TCP, IP, and lower) than HTTP. The transition in the stack between text and binary is arbitrary. The motivation for standardization is to draw on others' experience and operate with existing tools, however few in number, so running with a large herd is not a factor.

Comment: The operating within existing tools is the point I was making.  Not the large herd, poor word choice on my part. I was meaning to say that if it takes a custom apache plugin, or an unsupported one, to accomplish compressed http headers, it is sub-ideal.